# How do you get the initialized value of a global variable out of an object file?

Tags: global-variables, binutils, object-files

If you have an object file, how do you get the initialized value of a global variable in that object file's data segment?  For example, say I've done the following:

```
# I'm interested in the variable foo inside bar.o in libbar.a:
$ ar -x libbar.a bar.o
$ nm --print-size bar.o | grep foo
00000048 00000004 D foo
```

This tells me that `foo` is at offset 0x48 in the data segment with size 4, but how do I obtain the actual initialized value it obtains upon load?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
objdump -j.data -s bar.o
```

This gives a hexdump of the data segment, making it easy to look up values.  I've used `objdump -d` before to disassemble code, but the `-s` option is new to me.

Comment: On macOS the section seems to be named `__data`. You can get a list of sections with `objdump -h bar.o`.